# Beginner's Python- What is my Mistake?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is Sheldon Cooper's Friendship Algorithm.
Python code.
Please help me find the mistake.
I doubled checked it x200 times but can't seem to find it.
I'm in high school so this would be pretty easy for all of you.
.

```
print("The Friendship Algorithm \n By Dr. Sheldon Cooper Ph.D")
print("Place a phone call")
home = input("Are they home?")

if home == "yes":
print("Ask, would you like to share a meal?")
meal = input("What is their response?")
```

.

```
if meal == "yes":
    print("Dine together")
    print("Begin friendship!")
elif meal == "no":
    print("Ask, do you enjoy a hot beverage?")
```

.

```
    hot_beverage = input("What is their response?")
    if hot_beverage == "yes":
        beverage = input("Tea, coffee or cocoa?")
        if beverage == "tea":
            print("Have tea")
            print("Begin friendship!")
        elif beverage == "coffee":
            print("Have coffee")
            print("Begin friendship!")
        elif beverage == "cocoa":
            print("Have cocoa")
            print("Begin friendship!")
        else:
            print("That is not an option")
```

.

```
    elif hot_beverage == "no":
        while interest_cycle:
            print("Recreational activities: \n Tell me one of your interests.")
            interest = input("Do you share that interest?")
            if n > 6:
                print("Choose least objectional interest")
                interest_cycle = False
            elif interest == "no":
                print("Ask for another")
                n = n + 1
            elif interest == "yes":
                interest_cycle = False
                print("Ask, why don't we do that together?")
                print("Partake in interest")
                print("Begin friendship!")
```

.

```
else:
    print("That is not an option")
```

.

```
elif home == "no":
print("Leave message")
print("Wait for callback")

else:
print("That is not an option")
```

Comment: your indentation after `if home` is off

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly

Comment: You've not explained a problem, and *What is my mistake?* is not a question. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your question. It should clearly explain the problem you're having, and should actually ask a specific question related to that code.

Comment: suggestion: start with just the very smallest subpart that you can get to work, then *slowly and carefully* add lines of code, running to confirm it works at each step. if you do this, you will definitely find the bug :) (also, make sure that everything intended to be in the scope of `if` is indented :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nicely written ! I made a few modifications to make it work on my computer.

Firstly I replaced all the `input()` with `raw_input`, this way you won't have to enter your answer with quotions.

Secondly, I had to rework the indentations on my side.

And lastly, I edited your while loop to hopefully make it look more like the actual flow chart.

If I were you, I would also add some conditions to prevent the program from ending if the user enters a bad value.

I hope it works for you !

```
print("The Friendship Algorithm \n By Dr. Sheldon Cooper Ph.D")
print("Place a phone call")
home = raw_input("Are they home?")

if home == "yes":
    print("Ask, would you like to share a meal?")
    meal = raw_input("What is their response?")

    if meal == "yes":
        print("Dine together")
        print("Begin friendship!")
    elif meal == "no":
        print("Ask, do you enjoy a hot beverage?")
        hot_beverage = raw_input("What is their response?")
        if hot_beverage == "yes":
            beverage = raw_input("Tea, coffee or cocoa?")
            if beverage == "tea":
                print("Have tea")
                print("Begin friendship!")
            elif beverage == "coffee":
                print("Have coffee")
                print("Begin friendship!")
            elif beverage == "cocoa":
                print("Have cocoa")
                print("Begin friendship!")
            else:
                print("That is not an option")

        elif hot_beverage == "no":
            n = 0
            while n<= 6:
                print("Recreational activities: \n Tell me one of your interests.")
                interest = raw_input("Do you share that interest?")

                if interest == "no":
                    print("Ask for another")
                    n = n + 1
                elif interest == "yes":
                    print("Ask, why don't we do that together?")
                    print("Partake in interest")
                    print("Begin friendship!")
                    break

                else:
                    print("That is not an option")


elif home == "no":
    print("Leave message")
    print("Wait for callback")

else:
    print("That is not an option")
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the while loop will not execute because you have not set the value for `interest_cycle` hence it will `return None` whereas in python None is equivalent to `False` when converted to boolean.
Please refer to this for more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-construct-while-loops-in-python-3

And also check your indentation on the `if home == "yes":`, `elif home == "no":`
 and `else:`.

Good work on the code. I like the readability.